# Joining to multicast groups on newly created interfaces with IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP

Tags: networking, udp, multicast, mdns

I have an mDNS responder which must respond to multicast queries on all interfaces.

For example, on startup it adds its socket to multicast groups using an `ethernet` interface.

Then I connect to a VPN and a new `ppp` interface emerge. How to add my socket to the newly created interfaces in order to be able to respond on them as well?

Example:

1. I start my mDNS responder application. It creates a UDP socket and binds it to `INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0)`. Then the socket joins the mDNS multicast group on `ethernet` interface - e.g. address `224.0.0.251`, interface `192.168.0.102`.
2. I run `dig @224.0.0.251 hedgaron-debian-test.local -p 5353` and receive an answer.
3. I connect to a VPN and a new `tun0` interface is being created.
4. I run `dig @224.0.0.251 hedgaron-debian-test.local -p 5353` once more and my query does not make it through, because (I guess) the responder`s socket is not joined to the multicast group on the newly created interface. Ofc, this time dig makes a query from the new interface.

NOTE: I heard `l2tp/ipsec` VPN doesn't work alongside with `ethernet`. Maybe it is an issue as well.

How to make the socket accept multicast packets on all interfaces?

Comment: Please add more detail about what you tried and what went wrong. See [mcve]

Comment: what happens when you connect to the vpn first?

Comment: it works for both VPN and ethernet, but doesn't accept queries from ethernet if VPN is still enabled. I guess because of l2tp.

Comment: You are using a link-local (`224.0.0.251`) multicast group that cannot be sent to a different link (anything in the `224.0.0.0/24` range).

Comment: I guess I can't use another group with mDNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. `l2tp/ipsec` is not an issue.

The socket must be joined to a multigroup on **every** interface, not just on `0.0.0.0`. To join newly created interfaces in background, the application must start a thread which rejoins on all interfaces every N seconds.

It allows the socket to accept multicast packets from all networks.